# Git: How to access a file that is part of another commit, but has not yet been pushed

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have two sibling branches, Old and New. Old is currently committed, but pending code review (it has not been pushed to remote). New is a branch I just opened.

My work on New needs a file, foo.java, that I wrote as part of Old, and is currently in code review. How can I give the New branch access to foo.java, without pushing Old?

I've tried running this while on New:
`git checkout Old -- foo.java`

With result: `error: pathspec 'foo.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Similarly: `git show Old:foo.java` gives
`fatal: Path 'foo.java' does not exist in 'Old'`

Bonus points if there's a way to do so such that if my code review requires changes to foo.java, there can be a clean merge after Old is pushed and New is rebased.

Comment: maybe your foo.java is in subdir(s)?

Comment: I'm confused on a couple points. Are `old` and `new` in the same clone? If so I don't understand the relevance that it hasn't been pushed. (But I guess conversely, if not that would explain the problem with your `git checkout` command.) Also, while it may not matter - how is anyone reviewing your code if it hasn't been pushed? The point of the remote repo is that it's the hub for collaboration...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger They are in the same local repo, if that's what you mean. I don't think it matters, it's a process that doesn't rely on git push to get the code to an online review tool.

Comment: @TLJ I tried every path variation (`foo.java`, `/foo.java`, `dir1/foo/java`, `/dir1/foo.java`, etc.) nothing worked.

Comment: Is it not useful for you to just fork a branch from Old to start working on?

Comment: @mintychai this was actually exactly what I needed

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to add the `foo.java` when you were committing those changes to `Old`?

Comment: @Stack Haha awesome. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return to `Old` and fork a branch from there to start working.